# Firebase database : How can i get key and join?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to use the data stored in the Firebases Database to create a recycler view that repeats, but the problem is that I have to join and I do not know how to do it in my case.

[image: Database Nodes]

I want to get data under Requestor key values and I want to use user key data. What I want to do is finding only under requestor user-id and get the data full name and image.

Maybe it needs joining? How can I do that?

**This is my fragment for getting the data under requestor**

```
package com.example.together.fragment;


public class PetchingLoungeFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "PetFirendsFragment";

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    PetchingLoungeAdapter petchingLoungeAdapter;
    List<Lounge> requestorUserList;
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        Log.d(TAG, "분양키 리스트 목록처음"+requestorUserList);

        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pet_firends, container, false);

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);



        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("PetchingBunyang").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("Requestor");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {


                for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    Lounge lounge = childSnapshot.getValue(Lounge.class);
                    String key = childSnapshot.getKey();

                    Log.d(TAG, "라운지키"+key);

                    //각 신청키
                    lounge.setRequestorId(key);

                    requestorUserList.add(lounge);

                    Log.d(TAG, "신청자키: "+requestorUserList);
                    Log.d(TAG, "신청: "+lounge);


                }


                Collections.reverse(requestorUserList);
                petchingLoungeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });



        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        requestorUserList = new ArrayList<>();
        petchingLoungeAdapter = new PetchingLoungeAdapter(getContext(), requestorUserList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(petchingLoungeAdapter);



        return view;


    }


}
```

**This is my recycler-view adapter**

```
package com.example.together.adapter;

public class PetchingLoungeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PetchingLoungeAdapter.MyViewHolder> {


    private static final String TAG = "PetchingBunyangAdapter";

    FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
    DatabaseReference reference;

    Context mContext;
    List<Lounge> mLounge;

    public PetchingLoungeAdapter(Context mContext, List<Lounge> mLounge) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mLounge = mLounge;
    }



    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_petching_lounge, parent, false);
        return new PetchingLoungeAdapter.MyViewHolder(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder viewHolder, int position)
    {

        final Lounge lounge = mLounge.get(position);
        getRequestorUserInfo(lounge.getRequestorId(), viewHolder.img_requestor, viewHolder.requestor_name);



        viewHolder.img_requestor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), PetchingBunyangDetailInfo.class);

               // intent.putExtra("petBunyangId",mUser.get(position).getPetBunyangId());

                mContext.startActivity(intent);


            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return mLounge.size();
                //mPetchingLounge.size();
    }



    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {

        public Button allow, refuse;
        public ImageView img_requestor;
        public TextView requestor_name;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);

            img_requestor = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_requestor);

            allow = itemView.findViewById(R.id.allow);
            refuse = itemView.findViewById(R.id.refuse);

            requestor_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.requestor_name);


        }
    }



    // 펫 정보 이름, 나이, 견종, 성별,
    private void getRequestorUserInfo(String petbunyangid, final ImageView imageView, final TextView petName)
    {


        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("Requestor").child(petbunyangid);
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Lounge lounge = dataSnapshot.getValue(Lounge.class);

                lounge.getRequestorId();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options:
1. Get all user list and map the data.
2. Add get query for each user id.

I prefer Option 2.

Snippet:

```
  List<UserBean> userBeanList= new  ArrayList<>();
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("PetchingBunyang").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("Requestor");
    reference.addSingleValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //got all the list of the user ids 
            //userList is array of String which contains all userIds

            for (String userid : userList) {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userid).addSingleValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        //got all the list of the user ids
                        //
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: sorry for latte !!! i have some private problem ... so Thank you so much

Comment: No issue.. Happy coding

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("PetchingBunyang").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("Requestor");
DatabaseReference userReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
     for(DataSnapshot ds : datas.getChildren()){
          String id = ds.getKey();

          userReference.child(id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
              @Override
           public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String fullName = dataSnapshot.child("fullname").getValue(String.class);
                String imageUrl = dataSnapshot.child("imageUrl").getValue(String.class);
               }
              @Override
          public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { 
             throw databaseError.toException(); 
               }
           });
      }
    }
 }
   @Override
public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { 
     throw databaseError.toException(); 
    }
 });
```

First add a reference to child `Requestor` then loop inside it twice to be able to get the `userid` that has the value `true`. Then after retrieving the `userid` add another reference to node `Users` and retrieve the data of that user.